# Are there any special interactions between specific heroes in All Heroes mode of Retribution?

Tags: overwatch

Just curious if there's any specific combinations of heroes that would lead to unique voice lines/banter between them.

Love the lore in the game, would like to see if more exists outside of the regular story mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like it, sorry. That would be cool if there were, though!